# SQL - How do I grab the top row of a group based on a changing condition, without selecting rows under it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

Say I used a query below:

```
select * from GenericTable order by ID, DATE
```

and received the following table.

```
ID:     DATE:      VALUE1:       VALUE2:
----------------------------------------
 1     6/1/18           22            24
 1     7/1/18           23            25
 1     8/1/18           24            25
 2    6/28/18           31            46
 2    6/30/18           33            11
 2     7/1/18           21            10
```

I need to refine that query to select only a single datarow per `ID` based on a changing date condition `(DATE <= @DateVar)`.  For instance, `if @DateVar = '6/15/18'`, I should get the following table:

```
ID:     DATE:      VALUE1:       VALUE2:
----------------------------------------
 1     6/1/18           22            24
```

`If @DateVar = 6/29`, I should get:

```
ID:     DATE:      VALUE1:       VALUE2:
----------------------------------------
 1     6/1/18           22            24
 2    6/28/18           31            46
```

And if I do `@DateVar = 7/15`, I should get:

```
ID:     DATE:      VALUE1:       VALUE2:
----------------------------------------
 1     7/1/18           23            25
 2     7/1/18           21            10
```

Tracking `Row#` through partitioning and selecting `Row# = 1` was my original solution, but how would I craft a partition that only accounted for `DATE <= @DateVar` so that, say, for `@DateVar = 6/30`, I would get the following to select `Row# = 1` from?

```
ID:     DATE:      VALUE1:       VALUE2:     ROW#:
--------------------------------------------------
 1     7/1/18           23            25         1
 1     8/1/18           24            25         2
 2    6/30/18           33            11         1
 2     7/1/18           21            10         2
```

Comment: What is your SQL looks like? Did you try anything, or up do you want us to create the SQL for you?

Comment: Why do you assert row id=1 row#=1 will be pulled when your datevar is <= 6/30? (Last data block) To me looks like it will exclude all rows from id 1, no?

Comment: i.e. why does `select * from (select *, row_number over(partition by id order by date desc) as rown from GenericTable where date <= @datevar) t where t.rown=1` NOT work?

Comment: and more importantly, how is `@DateVar = 6/30` showing dates after 6/30 (7/1,8/1) in the last data block. ? it has different logic I guess!

Comment: @isr5 he says in the para above words to the effect of "i would only get the rows numbered row# = 1 in this grid" (how i interpret it) hence my question,. I can work out why he gets id=2 row#=1 but i cannot work out why he would get id=1, row#=1 if the date filter is before 6/30

Comment: @CaiusJard still unclear for me, how is it possible to get dates grater than `@DateVar <= 6/30`. ? As for the row numbering, it's clearly not an issue here, (as you've mentioned in your previous comment `partition by id order by date` should do it.

Comment: I think we might be asking him the same question.. I don't think dates greater than 6/30 should be returned, he's just providing us with 4 rows and then saying "I should only get two of these 4 rows" as though he's explaining what all his table data is and then asserting what would be filtered - my question (and I suspect yours also) is "why do you assert you will get two rows when one of those rows date is greater than 6/30" (but I'm also pondering that your q might be "why do you assert 4 rows when 3 have a date greater"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use row_number:

```
select top 1 with ties *
from GenericTable
where [DATE] <= @DateVar
order by row_number() over (partition by ID order by [DATE] desc)
```

Here is how row_number helps you... Whenever you need to return the whole row when an aggregate is needed on only a portion of the row then row_number (or other windows functions) came into play.

Move the row_number to the select part and get rid of the top 1 with ties to see what the data set really looks like.

Most people would write it this way, but I like making it look tighter:

```
;with cte as 
(
select *,rn = row_number() over (partition by ID order by date desc)
from [table]
where [DATE] <= @DateVar
)
select * 
from cte 
where rn=1
```

Comment: I think TOP 1 WITH TIES is a special case though, and TOP 2 WITH TIES isn't necessarily the same as WHERE rownum <= 2, so I'd probably avoid the inference that these two queries are the same - they function that way for top 1 / rn = 1 but that's it.. to get a with ties to work the same as rn <= 2 you'd have to know how many rows X were in first place so you could top X + 1 with ties, right?

Comment: The request is specifically for rn=1 but if it was for top 5 for example, I would use the CTE approach or cross apply.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Table_1', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE dbo.Table_1; END;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1 (
    ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY
    );
INSERT dbo.Table_1 (ID) VALUES (1), (2);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Table_2', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE dbo.Table_2; END;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_2 (
    t1_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_table2_t1ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Table_1 (ID),
    SomeDate date NOT NULL,
    Value1 INT NOT NULL,
    Value2 INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_table2 PRIMARY KEY (t1_ID, SomeDate) 
    );
INSERT dbo.Table_2 (t1_ID, SomeDate, Value1, Value2) VALUES 
    (1, '20180601', 22, 24),
    (1, '20180701', 23, 25),
    (1, '20180801', 24, 25),
    (2, '20180628', 31, 46),
    (2, '20180630', 33, 11),
    (2, '20180701', 21, 10);

--==================================================================

DECLARE @DateVar DATE = '20180710';

SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    tx.SomeDate,
    tx.Value1,
    tx.Value2
FROM
    dbo.Table_1 t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            t2  .t1_ID,
            t2.SomeDate,
            t2.Value1,
            t2.Value2
        FROM
            dbo.Table_2 t2
        WHERE 
            t1.ID = t2.t1_ID
            AND t2.SomeDate <= @DateVar
        ORDER BY 
            t2.SomeDate DESC
        ) tx;
```

Result...

```
ID          SomeDate   Value1      Value2
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           2018-07-01 23          25
2           2018-07-01 21          10
```

Comment: I always wondered which was better - `cross apply top 1 coordinated query`, or `where (row_number over) = 1`. Feels like analytic approach only does one table scan.. Maybe cross apply has some optimizer magic too, and theyre same.. Do you know?

Comment: It depends on what indexes are available. So, based the example data I provided, table_2 has a PK of (t1_ID, SomeDate). The RN method ...ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.t1_ID ORDER BY t2.SomeDate DESC)... would cause a sort operation, making it more expensive. If, on the otherhand, the PK were defined as (t1_ID, SomeDate DESC) then the same RN would not need the sort operation making it faster than my posted solution. Moral of the story... write it both ways and see which one works best in the specific environment.